# The usage of Cassandra's internal keyspace "system"

Tags: nosql, cassandra

The default Cassandra systems keyspace `system` is present in all Cassandra installations.

Judging from the output of the `describe keyspace` command the keyspace is used partly for "persistent metadata for the local node" (`LocationInfo`) and partly for "hinted handoff data".

- What persistent metadata for the local node is stored in `system/LocationInfo`?
- What is the definition of hinted handoff in Cassandra terminology?
- What hinted handoff data is stored in the `system` keyspace?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"**[Hinted handoff](http://wiki.apache.org/cassandra/HintedHandoff)** means that if a node that should receive a write is down, Cassandra will send that write to another node with a "hint" saying that when the destination node becomes available again, the write should be forwarded there."

After the answer on question two I believe the third question becomes obsolete (?)

And finally the first question:
The token, cluster name, and whether the node is bootstrapped or not will be stored in system. (thanks driftx)